# kubernetes cluster setup on bare metal

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos7

I am trying to setup 3 node kubernetes cluster on bare metal(1 master and 2 worker nodes). I am following the below links for setup https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-1-7-centos7-rhel7/
and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-centos

Besides the prerequisites mentioned in the above link I have also disabled swap(systemctl stop firewalld), disabled selinux policy(sudo setenforce 0) and updated Iptables settings

```
cat  < /etc/sysctl.d/master_node_name
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF
sysctl --system
```

But as soon as I start `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.140.48`(on master node)
I get the following errors in docker for k8s_kube-controller-manager :

```
E0204 1 leaderelection.go:330 error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get https://192.168.140.48:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager?timeout=10s: Forbidden
```

and for docker  k8s_kube-scheduler as below

```
E0204 1 reflector.go:123 k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.140.48:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
E0204 10:45:44.629865       1 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:250: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.140.48:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: Forbidden
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the `kubeadm init` as root and have you tried not setting the `apiserver-advertise-address`?

Comment: Hi Crou, Thanks for your quick response. yes i do the run the kubeadm init as root and apiserver-advertise-address value is 192.168.140.48(my master node ip). However i was not specfying pod-network which I am trying right now.

Comment: It did not work out, any suggestion or debugging tips are welcome.

Comment: I would try just plaint `kubeadm init` as it will detect everything automatically. Also it will show the issues with pre-flight which can be checked with [Troubleshooting kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/) page.